# No valid coverage data available in Rails stats report

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, report

`No valid coverage data available

Tracking and trending code coverage works best when like is compared with like. In  this     regard it is best to only track builds when all unit tests are passing.

This plugin will not report code coverage until there is at least one stable build.`

what should i do to have a rails stats report

Comment: "works best when like is compared with like." I am not getting your question exactly can you please elaborate do you want code coverage then use `gem metric_fu`. If you want to track your status of rails application use `gem resque`

Comment: the thing is i have configured my build with rails stats report, when i open the rails stats report it displays as i mentioned above but rails report displays the report for only one build. rest of the builds displays the above one. please let me know what am i supposed to do and may i know what do you mean by "works best when like is compared with like."

Comment: "Tracking and trending code coverage works best **when like is compared with like.** In this regard it is best to only track builds when all unit tests are passing." from your post

Comment: can you please let me know more clearly

Comment: You configured your build through travis ?

Comment: no i didn't use travis, actually i am using jenkins  for deploying

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35134/discussion-between-krs-and-rajarshi)

Comment: can you please use travis it is free I can help you and it is very efficient for any kind of projects even rails main repository use it

Comment: I don't know what problem you have exactly but this may help? http://timvoet.com/2011/05/19/jenkins-rails-code-coverage-a-gotcha/

Answer (score 1):

@krs - From what you've said in your comments, you are correct.

`rails stats` only provides code coverage metrics for tests at that point in time. `rails stats` does not intend to keep data between builds and report test results vs. code converage.

You can connect your CI to an external service to see test coverage vs. test results. (EG, https://coveralls.io).

Answer (score 0):

Please add coverage.xml file outside the project.It works fine for me.